SwiftUI Google Sign In fails in Simulator
When trying to use Google Sign In with the simulator I get a full hang of the app when calling this:
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: presentingVC) { user, error in
    if let error = error {
        self.errorMessage = "error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
    }
    self.checkStatus()
}

The app and the call back works in a real device but hangs on the Simulator.
The APP_ID and URL schemes I believe are well defined in the Info.plist file.
Any idea? Thanks in advance.
